# SML greater of two lists

Tags: function, sml, smlnj

Need help with an SML problem I can't seem to solve. Basically I have two list and I need to return the greater from each list.

Example call:

```
Greater([8,4,12,5,6],[2,6,14,4,5]);
```

Would return (8,6,14,6).

I just started working with lists in SML and not even sure where to start on this.

Comment: There are only four values in the return. Should the return value be (8,6,14,5,6)?

Answer (score 3):

```
val greater = List.map Int.max o ListPair.zip
```

Or to expand that out:

```
fun greater(nil, nil)     = nil
  | greater(x::xs, y::ys) = (if x > y then x else y)::greater(xs, ys)
  | greater(_, _)         = raise Domain
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! Is there anyway of doing this in terms of a function though? Just trying to see how it all breaks down. Never used ListPair.zip so not sure what that exactly does.

Comment: @user3091510, added self-contained implementation.

Comment: Oh, and `ListPair.zip` creates a list of pairs from a pair of lists.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have two lists of equal lengths you could define this function:

```
fun greater nil nil = nil
  | greater (x::xs) (y::ys) = 
       if x > y then x::(greater xs ys) else y::(greater xs ys);
```

Or alternatively, by reducing the problem to a mapping from a list of int pairs to a list of ints:

```
fun zip nil nil = nil
  | zip (x::xs) (y::ys) = (x,y)::(zip xs ys);

fun max (x,y) = if x > y then x else y;

fun greater xs ys = map max (zip xs ys);
```

Note that lists in ML are denoted as `[1,2,3]` and not `(1,2,3)`, which is a tuple with three elements. This function is then called as:

```
- greater [1,2,3,4] [2,3,4,5];
val it = [2,3,4,5] : int list

- greater [~1,8,3] [8,~1,~2];
val it = [8,8,3] : int list
```

Answer (score 1):

even better:

```
val greater = ListPair.map Int.max
```